# Creating Multible IDs for multible Buttons in one <Input> Tag

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I'm working on a TicTacToe game using Django/Djangotemplates, Python and a bit Javascript. I've come across a problem tho. i only have one Button which is for-looped 9 times. its ID is its index. Now I'm not certain how to add the {{index}} which i defined in the for loop in the javascript onclick function.

**here the html template**

```
             <div class="grid-container">
               {% for index in object.board %}
               <div class="grid-item">
                   <input onclick="change(button.id)" class="buttonsize btn-outline-purple" type="submit" value="" name="button" id="{{index}}">
               </div>
               {% endfor %}
           </div>
       </div>
   </article>
</form>

<script>
   function change(inputid){
       console.log("test")
       var elem = document.getElementById(inputid);
       if (elem.value=="") elem.value = "X"
   }
</script>
```

**here the models.py**

```
class TicTacToe(models.Model):
    player1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="X", related_name="tictactoe_as_player1")
    player2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="O", related_name="tictactoe_as_player2")
    current_player = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tictactoe_current_player")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    board = models.CharField(max_length=9, default="012345678")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tictactoe-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**and here the views.py**

```
class TicTacToeCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = TicTacToe
    template_name = 'website/newgame_form.html'
    fields = ['player1', 'player2', 'current_player', 'title', 'board']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class TicTacToeDetailView(UpdateView):
    model = TicTacToe
    fields = ['player1', 'player2', 'current_player', 'title', 'board']

    def clean(self):
        if 'button0' in self.data:
            print('button0')
```

i also got a database but there is really not much in there except the player IDs

Answer (score 1):

Adding index to the onclick should be OK

```
                   <input onclick="change({{index}})" class="buttonsize btn-outline-purple" type="submit" value="" name="button" id="{{index}}">
```